# How to initialize an array object

Tags: arrays, initialization

Why I am getting the error while runtime:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at arrayTest.main(arrayTest.java:5)

Source code is as following:

```java
public class arrayTest{
    int b;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        arrayTest[] a= new arrayTest[2];
        a[0].b=10;
        System.out.println(a[0].b);
    }
}
```

Thanks
Sunil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't added any `arrayTest` instances to your array. You've only initialized the array, so `arrayTest[0]` is `null`. To add objects to the array:

```java
arrayTest[0] = new arrayTest();
arrayTest[1] = new arrayTest();
```

Comment: I added arrayTest instances. No error now while runtime. Thanks Matt!

Answer (score 1):

When doing Object-Oriented-Programming (OOP) you need to think a bit differently.

Here what you are doing is creating a new object arrayTest from the class arrayTest.

This object need a constructor and fields which are properties so it can be well defined for instance: size, age or eyes colour for a person.

Here what do you want your object to be?

For instance, I want to do an ArrayList of `n` object of the same type :
First, my field is going to be an ArrayList because that's what I want to create.

I have the following class :

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class arrayTestType {
    private final ArrayList arrayTest;
}
```

What should my constructor return?

Well, an array of type Type with n elements is `ArrayList<Type>(n)`
so my constructor should be written like this :

```java
public arrayTestType(Type type, int length) {
    arrayTest = new ArrayList<Type>(length);
}
```

So finally our class is :

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class arrayTestType {
    private final ArrayList arrayTest;

    public arrayTestType(Type type, int length){
        arrayTest = new ArrayList<Type>(length);
    }
}
```

Now when we are going to call :

```java
arrayTestType stringArrayOfLength5 = new arrayTestType<String>(5);
```

We are going to get an object well defined.
Now you need to add things in order for it not to be null hence the null pointer ! 
Good luck !